# How to update the JSPM modules to the latest version?

Tags: jspm

Does the command **jspm install .** update the packages to the latest version?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`jspm install` installs the latest versions of packages listed in the package.json respecting semver ranges defined in it. Once installed, exact versions numbers(not ranges) are stored in jspm's config.js. The subsequent `jspm install`s will install specific versions stored in the config.js. To update packages to the latest version (but still within semver ranges defined in the package.json) one has to run `jspm update`.

See also:

- [JSPM docs - Reproductible installs](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/installing-packages.md#reproducible-installs)
- [JSPM docs - Updating packages](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/installing-packages.md#updating-packages)

Comment: `jspm install` will install the version *ranges* specified in `package.json` (in the `jspm` section), not `config.json`. So if you want it to always install a specific version, make sure a single version (not range) is specified in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

yes `jspm install` installs the latest versions of packages defined in the `jspm` property of the package.json file.

But it exists a command that updates all packages: `jspm update`, or only one package: `jspm update <package>`.

See the documentation here: https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/installing-packages.md#updating-packages